# apache log is filled with erros and warnings almost 25 gb each time

Tags: php

Here is my code to fetch data from websites which have there some data stores in txt files, I just give the urls and it starts fetching the data

```
foreach ($collector_urls as $key => $value) {
    $k=0;
    try{
        $file=fopen($value,"r");
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $str=fgets($file);
            $new_str=explode(".",$str);
            if(is_numeric($new_str[0])){
                // if (!in_array($str,$ip_array))
                $array[$ip_count++]=$str;

            }
        }

        $log[$name_in_key]=json_encode(array('status'=>'success','count'=>$k,'key'=>$name_in_key,'url'=>$value));
    }catch(Exception $e){
        print("Something wrong with file ".$value."<br>");
        $log->$name_in_key=array('status'=>'failed','count'=>0);
    }
}
```

while the code does so , some warnings arrive such has invalid resource content for fopen, fgets and isnumeric

data is very very huge so I might consider about 300000 rows of error each time it executes , 
what is actually my problem is it fills almost 25 gb of meemory when executed inside apache log with errors and warnings

is there a way I can tell apche not to log warnings and errors inside log file or some other method also should I need to change some part of code which I am doing wrong

Need suggestions , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable apache error log file by editing you vhost config file for the given domain by entering this line:

```
ErrorLog /dev/null
```

But I`ll advise you to fix the warnings and errors instead of disabling error log.

Comment: also I need to ask you that my files I am reading online are craeting copy of tmp files and which are not being removed which in turn are filling up the space, can you suggest anything for that